# Oversized line spacing in moderncv CV title

Tags: spacing, moderncv

In this example from my CV the spacing between the address line and the next line is too large:

[image: CV title]

I suspect that this issue is caused by the large phone symbol which used to be a different, smaller symbol:

[image: old phone symbol]

[**EDIT:** No, that's not it. If I replace the line

```
\mobile{1234}
```

with

```
\extrainfo{\faMobile \, 1234}
```

I get a smaller symbol but the oversized spacing remains.]

How can I reduce the line spacing here?

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Simon}
\familyname{Jakobi}
\address{Address part 1}{Address part 2}
\mobile{123}
\email{simon.jakobi@gmail.com}
\homepage{github.com/sjakobi}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The spacing is caused by an empty line which is created when the `moderncv` headstyle calls `\null` in `vmode`.
You can avoid it by temporarily redefining `\null` to leave `vmode`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Simon}
\familyname{Jakobi}
\address{Address part 1}{Address part 2}
\mobile{123}
\email{simon.jakobi@gmail.com}
\homepage{github.com/sjakobi}

\begin{document}
{
  \def\null{\leavevmode\hbox{}}%
  \makecvtitle
}
\end{document}
```

[image]